# JavaScript: Converting expression to string

Tags: javascript, string, casting, type-conversion, expression

I am trying to find a way to cast an expression such as a condition statement to a string without having the expression being processed.

I tried using the .toString() method on the 'condition' parameter in the following 'assert' function.

```
const config = {
  usernme: 'username1',
  password: 'password1'
}

function assert(condition, message) {
  if (!condition) {
    message = message || `Assertion failed: ${condition.toString()}`;
    if (typeof Error !== "undefined") {
      throw new Error(message);
    }
    throw message; // Fallback
  }
}

assert('username' in config);
```

Actual error message: `Assertion failed: false`

Anticipated error message: `Assertion failed: 'username' in config`

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do it like that; the expression is evaluated before your function is even called, and only its resulting value is passed to your function. You could supply the expression as a string to begin with, and evaluate it with `eval(condition)`, but be warned that `eval` is frowned upon as it can be easy to accidentally introduce security vulnerabilities that way.

The way `console.assert()` handles this is that the expression is one argument, and then a custom label (as a string) is a second argument, so you can specify the label yourself, including just copy/pasting the expression and putting it in quotes for a string.